# Should I approve edits when the question should be deleted?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I did a search on Meta for this, but didn't find a concrete answer. I have found very diverse opinions instead.

The situation happens when I'm presented with a Suggested Edit review, and I see that the edit is correct and valid. However, it's an edit to a question that should be flagged for deletion rather than edited.

I'm new at approving edits so not sure what the correct behavior is. Right now, I'm skipping the edits because I don't know what to do, but I'd like to know exactly what to do, and in case of rejection, which option to choose. Should I use "Invalid Edit"? Should I only care about the edit and let other people handle the rejection or approval of the question or answer?

In any case, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It *should* be deleted doesn't mean that it *will* be deleted.

Comment: If nothing else improving formatting, spelling and grammar of the post  should help make it easier for other reviewers to determine if the post should be deleted.

Comment: @user000001 you're correct, what I mean is if I consider the post SHOULD be deleted. Since I'm required to do this, my subjectiveness comes in play, and that's a given. But I'm wondering more about the objective part rather than the subjective side of things

Comment: @Fabio yes what I meant is that since the post could stay around anyway, improving it is not necessarily futile.

Comment: You should certainly flag the bad posts, or cast a close vote once you have the privilege. Beyond that, I've partly been wondering as well. What I've mostly done so far is skip the edit review if the question clearly looks like a lost cause. If the question isn't *that* bad, and it's a really good and comprehensive edit, I would be more inclined to approve the edit anyway.

Comment: I normally would reject those edits. In the long run it makes not much difference though. If the post is deleted then the +2 from the approved edit is lost anyway.

Comment: Overmeta: [Is “don't polish turds” a valid edit rejection reason?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155961/262399) and some related questions.

Comment: If it’s useful, approve, please.

Answer (score 12):

Pointless edits should be rejected.

An edit that doesn't improve a low-quality post to the point that it no longer needs to be deleted is too minor. It's pointless.

Comment: i find it funny that this answer was edited to change the wording

Comment: @pnuts (i) Great! (ii) Review *is* a lot about VLQ and flagging, not that has anything to do with this. (iii) No, just delete.

Comment: (i) No. (ii) Oh, that was a typo. But reviewing VLQ flags and CVs is a huge part of review. Still not seeing the relevance of it tho. (iii) Everybody can flag VLQ/NAA, I don't see how editing helps.